# Entity Framework 4: Access current datacontext in partial entity class

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I want to extend an EF entity in a partial class with methods and properties. I've done this quite often.
But now I would need to combine data from this entity with data from other entities. I would therefore need to able to access the entities objectcontext (if attached) to make these queries.
Is there a way to get the entities objectcontext from within it?

Thanx!

Comment: this dosent sound right, can you explain why this is required ? mayby ther is another way to get where you need to go (perhaps an association or a complex type)

Answer (score 2):

There is no build in way to get current `ObjectContext` from entity. Entities based on `EntityObject` class and POCO proxies uses `ObjecContext` internally but they don't expose it.

Adding such depnedency into your entities is considered as bad design so you should perhaps explain what you are trying to do and we can find other (better) solution.

Comment: Hi. Our entities will have a property "List<EntendedProperties>". These properties are defined in a meta structure (a few tables) in the database. If this property of the entity is accessed, I would need to gather the structure and the values from the database. Our design allows to extend the entities with "dynamic" properties.

Comment: I do however understand your concern regarding bad design..:) I might move this up to the business layer, but I consider it to be a low level abstraction which should reside in the persistence layer...

Answer (score 2):

Even though it is not recommended, and I myself don't use it (as Ladislav stated: bad design), I stumbled upon a solution:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/08/tip-24-how-to-get-the-objectcontext-from-an-entity.aspx

Extension Method:

```
public static ObjectContext GetContext( 
   this IEntityWithRelationships entity 
) 
{ 
    if (entity == null)  
       throw new ArgumentNullException("entity"); 

    var relationshipManager = entity.RelationshipManager; 

    var relatedEnd = relationshipManager.GetAllRelatedEnds() 
                                        .FirstOrDefault(); 

    if (relatedEnd == null)  
       throw new Exception("No relationships found"); 

    var query = relatedEnd.CreateSourceQuery() as ObjectQuery; 

    if (query == null)  
       throw new Exception("The Entity is Detached"); 

    return query.Context; 
}
```

within the entity

```
var myContext = this.GetContext() as MyEntities;
```

Comment: Put the code example directly into the answer, in case the referenced source disappears.

Comment: As the author of the article states, this will not work if the entity has no relationships. Alternatively, this can be done [via reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26212071/111794).