# why can't we get ObjectContext from an EntityObject

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

It is well know that if we have an EntityObject that there is no way to find the ObjectContext that it belongs to. That's fair enough I guess, but why is it that we can lazy load objects then? Surely the process of lazy loading has to get access to the ObjectContext in order to load the new objects?

Comment: Actually you can get `ObjectContext` from `EntityObject`: It is described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160218233919/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/08/tip-24-how-to-get-the-objectcontext-from-an-entity.aspx)..

Comment: Persistence ignorance is a great principle.

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6870033/111794) is limited in that it can only work if the entity has at least one relationship.

However, this can also be done via reflection:

```
public ObjectContext Context(EntityObject entity) {
    var relationshipManager = ((IEntityWithRelationships)entity).RelationshipManager;
    var wrappedOwnerProperty = relationshipManager.GetType().GetProperty("WrappedOwner",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var wrappedOwner = wrappedOwnerProperty.GetValue(relationshipManager);
    var contextProperty = wrappedOwner.GetType().GetProperty("Context");
    return (ObjectContext)contextProperty.GetValue(wrappedOwner);
}
```

In VB.NET:

```
Function Context(entity As EntityObject) As ObjectContext
    Dim relationshipManager = DirectCast(entity, IEntityWithRelationships).RelationshipManager
    Dim wrappedOwnerProperty = relationshipManager.GetType.GetProperty("WrappedOwner", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    Return wrappedOwnerProperty.GetValue(relationshipManager).Context
End Function
```

NB: This was tested under .NET Framework v. 4.5.1. YMMV, as this depends on the internal `WrappedOwner` property and the `Context` property on the internal `BaseEntityWrapper<TEntity>` class. Nevertheless, if earlier/leter versions of .NET have different internal properties/classes it should be simple enough to do something similar.

NB: This could further be improved by making it an extension method on `EntityObject`, and by taking a generic parameter to return a strongly typed `ObjectContext`. It could also be simplified by using some sort of method to get property values by name.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, given an object, we don't know what context it belongs to, or what session it is attached to. But Lazy Loading happens like this :

```
var firstPost = _Context.Posts.First()
var commentList = firstPost.Comments
```

When you say `_Context.Posts.First()` then one post is loaded.
Then when you say `firstPost.Comments` that's when the comments list is loaded.

This is possible because the type of your Comments field in your Post is probably an `IList` or some such generic interface : this is because EF4 can put a **proxy list** instead of the *actual comment list*. The **proxy list** knows about the _Context - knows about which session or context it is attached to. Hence it is able to load an *actual list* on demand.

Comment: I believe most navigation properties are marked as virtual and a proxy is used to intercept.

Comment: Yep bryan is right. Both in Nhibernate and EF4 we mark the many to X relationships as virtual and allow the ORM to create proxies which extend our classes. Lazy loading happens because the proxy contains a proxylist which is loaded on access