# EF getting the current ObjectContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I need to get the current context given an entity

I found this old article from 2009

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/08/tip-24-how-to-get-the-objectcontext-from-an-entity.aspx

given that we're now firmly in 2012, is there another way ?

UPDATE - here are some details on where this is reqd

Table1 - at the heart of the star shaped schema
      Tags nvarchar(300) 
      Idx identity int

Table2 - Tags reference
      TagID identity int
      TagText nvarchar(50)

Table3 - Rel between Table1 & Table2
     IDX FK 
     TagID FK

In the Context.SavingChanges() event for Table1
    the tags are parsed and saved to Table2 with the relationships added to Table3 using context from Table1

Any guidance on how to improve this are welcome

Comment: In 2012, it's harder. Because EF now supports POCOs.

Comment: @CraigStuntz, good to know EF supports POCO's, the Q is for entities, not POCO's, does that warrant a downvote though ?

Comment: Are you suggesting I downvoted you? If so, you are wrong.

Comment: @CraigStuntz i was wrong to assume ! my apologies !

Comment: There is no better method because you should never need this. Mentioned solution is something like a hack.

Comment: +1 to @LadislavMmka's comment. The hack mentioned will still work if you are using entity classes derived from EntityObject. If you are using POCO entity classes, then there is no reliable way to do this. It usually indicates an architectual problem if you need to do this.

Comment: @ArthurVickers this is for entity objects only, not POCO's, will update the Q to describe architecture where this is reqd !

Comment: @LadislavMrnka updated Q where this is helpful, any suggestions to improve are appreciated, thanks

Comment: @LadislavMrnka The referenced link only works if the entity has relationships. Alternatively, the object context can be retrieved [via reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26212071/111794).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the SavingChanges event handler, then you don't need to get the context from the entity, but rather the sender object of the event is the ObjectContext. This is the appropriate place to get the context in such a scenario. For example:

```
public void context_SavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ObjectContext context = sender as ObjectContext;
    // Do whatever you need to do...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The article shows how to get from IEntityWithRelationships, this is true, but if ud. For the current Context from the name of the entity, do not think you can do .... Maybe get the EntityContainerName:

```
public static string GetEntityContainerName(EntityObject entity)
{
        string entityContainerName = entity.EntityKey.EntityContainerName;
        return entityContainerName;
}
```

If you need reuse the current context, you need pass this as a parametter in your method.

regards

Comment: any guidance on how to use this ? can't seem to figure it out ! thanks