# Lock entity framework code on concurrent database updates

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, parallel-processing, entity-framework-5

I have the property `State` which, when set, updates an entity in the database.

The problem is that this property is being **set across multiple threads** and sometimes the job field is attached to two contexts at the same time, resulting in the following exception:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker.

I have tried to use a lock around the `using` statement, but this doesn't work:

```
private Job job;

public string State 
{
    get
    {
        return job.State;
    }
    set
    {
        lock (job)
        {
            using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
            {
                context.Jobs.Attach(job);
                job.State = value;

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with detaching the object and you loose nothing after, you can simply detach it from context after saving:

```
lock (job)
{
     using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
     {
           context.Jobs.Attach(job);
           job.State = value;
           context.SaveChanges();
           context.Detach(job);  // Detach the object
      }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I already tested a similar scenario and I found no problem. I suspect that the entity `job` was attached to some context before it enters the critical section. If `job` has some relations you can check whether an entity is attached to some context or not via the proposed way in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/08/tip-24-how-to-get-the-objectcontext-from-an-entity.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment but won't `job` be detached anyway when `context` is disposed on exiting the using statement?

Comment: You are right, and I don't understand why this happens even with *lock*. But I think the proposed answer works. However, I am eagerly looking for better and explanatory answer(s).

Comment: Thanks again, but it seems that locking on job wasn't actually locking.  Refer to my answer

Comment: @davenewza Very strange! Because I tested it and it works fine for me.

Comment: Strange indeed. Perhaps locking on entity instances isn't a good idea.

Comment: The problem reoccurred.  Detaching seems to be the fix now.

Comment: @davenewza Again, I am very very suspicious that before entering the critical section, the entity is already attached. Please check it. It is very easy to test if it is tracked by a context or not. The result is very determining and important for further investigations.

Comment: Even if `job` has no relationships, the object context can be accessed [via reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26212071/111794).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that locking on `job` wasn't working.  I am not sure why.

Implementing a dedicated lock `object` works perfectly:

```
private Job job;

private static object jobInstanceLock;

public string State 
{
    get
    {
        return job.State;
    }
    set
    {
        lock (jobInstanceLock)
        {
            using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
            {
                context.Jobs.Attach(job);
                job.State = value;

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```