# EF: Partial class - acces to the adapter?

Tags: entity-framework

let's say that I have a table `TabA`

```
namespace MyProject.Models.Database //<-- the same namespace as the EF's dbmx file
{
    public partial class TabA
    {
        public void Foo()
        { 
            //
        }
    }
 }
```

Inside the `Foo` method, I need to perform some operations on the other table which isn't asosiated with the `TabA` In the other words, I need to access to the Entity Framework adapter inside that method. Is it possible ?

### Edit

the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135157/106616

Comment: Does not seem to be something feasible in the construct of EF.  Your entity should be independant of other structures in the database.  You DO know, btw, that your method would not pass across to the client?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, I assume you have your reasons for wanting to work on another entity from the TabA entity.  If this is true, I can see two ways of doing this.

A)  If you want your changes to be applied at the same time as other potential changes to the TabA Entity, then you can always pass in the context as a parameter:

```
namespace MyProject.Models.Database //<-- the same namespace as the EF's dbmx file 
{ 
    public partial class TabA 
    { 
        public void Foo(YourDbContext context) 
        {  
            var otherTableQuery = from x in context.SecondTable
                             where ...
                             select x;

            foreach (var item in otherTableQuery)
            {
                item.Column1 = "A certain value";
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Your calling method might look like:

```
public void DoChangesToTabA()
{
    using ( YourDbContext context = new YourDbContext())
    {
        var tabAquery = from x in context.TabA
                        where ...
                        select x;

        foreach( var item in tabAQuery)
        {
            item.LastModified = DateTime.Now;

            if(???)
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now your changes will be applied the next time you call context.SaveChanges() from the calling method.