# Determine DbContext of object in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What do i have to do to find out the DbContext belonging to an object?

Background:
There is a long living object (selected by a DbContext) which is passed as parameter to some methods.

Within these methods modifications are made to the object which should be saved.
But for SaveChanges() i need the DbContext which i don't have in this moment.
I don't want to pass the DbContext as another parameter to the methods.

As an approach i can introduce a DbContext field in a partial class of the entity.
But is there something easier/more elegant?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210080/entity-framework-4-access-current-datacontext-in-partial-entity-class - it is still a valid answer for ef6 imho

Comment: @Artemiy: That won't work for Code-First.